# Appending data to a web page from a form using a JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, beginner, object-oriented, form, dom

Recently I've been reading about classes in JavaScript and decided to code this simple form to test them out. 
Even if the code works I am still pretty sure I lack understanding of classes and other js utilities, for example:

- did I need to use constructor in this class? if not when should I use it?
- is there a more efficient way to append multiple elements to the page?
- is the `try` and `catch` used properly in this case?
- generally speaking - is it correct example of where i should be using classes at all?

I'm not concerned with the looks of it but with functionality. Thanks for your help.

```js
const outp = document.getElementById('err');

class data{
  constructor(email, url, number){
    this.email = email;
    this.url = url;
    this.number = number;
  }
  static append(){
    var par = document.createElement('P');
    var em = document.createTextNode(email.value);
    var ur = document.createTextNode(url.value);
    var num = document.createTextNode(number.value);
    par.appendChild(em);
    par.appendChild(ur);
    par.appendChild(num);
    document.body.appendChild(par);
  }
}

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', () => {
  outp.innerHTML = "";
  let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  let url = document.getElementById('url').value;
  let number = document.getElementById('number').value;
  try{
    if(email == '' || url == '' || number == '' ) throw "Empty";
    data.append();
  }
  catch(err){
    outp.innerHTML = err;
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <label>
        <span>Email</span>
        <input type="email" id="email" required />
      </label><br>
      <label>
        <span>Url</span>
        <input type="url" id="url" required />
      </label><br>
      <label>
        <span>Number</span>
        <input type="number" id="number" required />
      </label>
      <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
      <p id="err"></p>
    </main>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention with class names is that they are usually written in pascal case, for example, `PascalCase`. So you should use `Data` for your class name.

While it's great that you're experimenting with javascript classes, I feel that they're not the right tool to use for this. The main idea of a class is that they can be used to create multiple objects based off the class.

Here's a pseudo-code example of when using a class is ideal.

```
class Vehicle {
    constructor(model, regNumber) {
        this.model = model;
        this.regNumber = regNumber;
    }

    start() {}
    accelerate(acc) {}
    brake() {}
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    // additional methods
}

const ford = new Car('Ford', 'HR28AP0000');
const auto = new Vehicle('ExampleDX', 'TN09XX0000');
```

The vehicle class has some attributes and methods. This example lends itself very well to the idea of classes.

For your code, it's best to use an `append` function instead.

I'd suggest looking up Object Oriented Programming. Some well written books and blogs will do a much better job of explaining when and where to use classes and objects and other OOP principles.

**Edit**: About try-catch, it's common to throw an `Error` object or one of it's descendants.

```
if(email == '' || url == '' || number == '' ) {
    throw new Error("Empty");
}
```